# how to develop feature of last successful login in android application?

Tags: android, session, authentication, sharedpreferences

I have made an android application,In that one login page is there with username and password Edittext and a login button,I want to develop one feature like "last successful" login time,I want the time of user's last successful login time,Can any one please tell me how to build such feature using Sharedpreference in android?I am login thru an api,Please suggest me and help me.Thank you

Comment: You can store the current time when you login in the `SharedPreferences` and then retrieve it whenever you require it

Comment: But where to put that variable..as all time it will be overwrite when I will login..Its the problem

Comment: So whenever you login isn't that a successful login?

Comment: @Apoorv-I need last login time and I am getting curent login time

Comment: @Jigarjims you can save the last login time at the logout screen.and whenever you login again you use the save value...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the SharedPreference Class as follows:-

```
public class SharedPref {

    public static final String PREF_NAME = "SHARED+PREF_FOR_TIME";

    public static final int TIME= "TIME";

    static Context _context;

    public SharedPref(Context c) {
        _context = c;
    }

    private static Editor getEditor() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return getPreferences().edit();
    }


    // for integer value
    public static void writeInteger(String key, int value) {
        getEditor().putInt(key, value).commit();

    }

    public static int readInteger(String key) {
        return getPreferences().getInt(key, 0);
    }
}
```

To Write the time in that Preference you have to write the following:-

```
SharedPref.writeInteger(SharedPref.TIME,time);
```

And for read the value from preference you write the following:-

```
int time_stored= SharedPref.readInteger(SharedPref.TIME);
```

Hope it will helps you a lot.May know your feedback.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to use shared preferences for that.

First add boolean value in shared preference like `isLogin(true/false)`.
By default `isLogin` vale is `false`.
Then once user logged in to the app change the value of `isLogin` to `true`. 
Also add few more keys which you want after login like username, password, etc.